# Attempt to use a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading

From what I can gather online the cause of this is most likely related to trying to copy a thread (which you can't do). I'm not sure why this problem is arising though. I do suspect which lines it arises in though.

Worker thread definition:

```
void WorkerThread(SharedLList<uint32_t> *workQueue, std::mutex *dataLock, uint8_t *data, uint32_t *seenStates, int depth)
```

Code in calling function:

```
SharedLList<uint32_t> workQueue;
std::mutex lock;
uint8_t *stateDepths = new uint8_t[s.GetMaxRank()];
uint32_t seenStates = 1;
int currDepth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = new std::thread(WorkerThread, std::ref(workQueue), std::ref(lock), stateDepths, std::ref(seenStates), currDepth);
    }
```

Thread
  -> Semantic Issue
      -> Attempt to use a deleted function

This is the line:

```
   __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
```

How can I fix this issue? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Click the edit button. It is located right beneath the last line of your entry.

Comment: You're passing `std::ref`s to `std::thread`'s constructor, yet your `WorkerThread` function expects pointers. Not sure that's possible. Shouldn't it be `std::thread(WorkerThread, &workQueue, &lock, stateDepths, &seenStates, currDepth);` or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your thread function is declared as accepting pointers as parameters. Yet you pass references as arguments. This mismatch exists for all pointer parameters except `uint8_t *data`.